# New use in Java (Can someone tell me why this is not working like i keep getting errors)

Tags: java

Can someone tell me where this is not working? Particularly the usage of the `new` keyword in the two methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class dotPractice {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount("Ade", 500.00);
    }
    public static void BankAccount(String Password, double balance) {
        // so i created a method for a bank account
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Password = input.nextLine();
        balance = input.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What are your inputs?

Answer (score 1):

The `BankAccount` should be a class not a static method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DotPractice {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    BankAccount b1=new BankAccount("Ade", 500.00);
  }

public class BankAccount {

  public BankAccount(String Password, double balance) {
    //so i created a method for a bank account
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    String Password=input.nextLine();
    balance=input.nextDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have defined `BankAccount` as a static method of the `dotPractice` class, when instead I think you want to define `BankAccount` as a class itself:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public BankAccount(String password, double balance)
    {
        //
    }
}

public class dotPractice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount("Ade", 500.00);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new methode (new BankAccount)
You need to create a new class (new .java file) called BankAccount with a constructor

```
public class BankAccount {
     public BankAccount(String password, double balance){
         Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
         String Password=input.nextLine();
         balance=input.nextDouble();
     }
}
```

than you can call from your main

```
BankAccount b1=new BankAccount("Ade", 500.00);
```

If you want to create a new object with the values u give it in the new BankAccount("Ade", 500.00);
the code should be this

```
  public class BankAccount {
         private String password;
         private double balance;
         public BankAccount(String password, double balance){
             this.password = password;
             this.balance = balance;
         }
    }
```

What this does, is store the give string and balance in variables which are privates to this class (bank account object) and only it can access it
you can set it to public and then u could write in the main
b1.balance and get the balance, but it's bad programming style.

Comment: la bla bla can you explain to me how to do that

Comment: U need a new file called BankAccount.java that contains the code I wrote. In order to create a 'new' instance, like u wrote, the object u try to instantiate can't be a method.
U paste in the new file the first piece of code I wrote, which defines a new class with a constructor (a method which automatically gets called when the object is created)

Actually, now I see it's kind of wrong what u wrote and I copied. when u write new BankAccount("bla",500.00);
Do you want that the object would hold the password and balance u give it or the user inputs it (that's what the scanner does) I edit my post